# Scanning DynamoDB table while inserting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When we scan a DynamoDB table, we can/should use `LastEvaluatedKey` to track the progress so that we can resume in case of failures. The documentation says that

`LastEvaluateKey` is `The primary key of the item where the operation stopped, inclusive of the previous result set. Use this value to start a new operation, excluding this value in the new request.`

My question is if I start a scan, pause, insert a few rows and resume the scan from the previous `LastEvaluatedKey`, will I get those new rows after resuming the scan?

My guess is I might miss some of all of the new rows because the new keys will be hashed and the values could be smaller than `LastEvaluatedKey`.

Is my guess right? Any explanation or documentation links are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is going sequentially through your data, and it does not know about all items that were added in the process:

> Scan operations proceed sequentially; however, for faster performance
>   on a large table or secondary index, applications can request a
>   parallel Scan operation by providing the Segment and TotalSegments
>   parameters.

Not only it can miss some of the items that were added after you've started scanning it can also miss some of the items that were added **before** the scan started if you are using eventually consistent read:

> Scan uses eventually consistent reads when accessing the data in a
>   table; therefore, the result set might not include the changes to data
>   in the table immediately before the operation began.

If you need to keep track of items that were added after you've started a scan you can use [DynamoDB streams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) for that.